# Bloat on Materialized Views

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

The Postgres documentation says that materialized views with concurrent refreshes generate bloat as usual tables, because it executes deletes and inserts. For usual tables, there are some queries to monitor the table bloat.

Is there a way to monitor bloat on materialized views?

Comment: A materialized view is a table as well. You can use the same queries